# Error in R.java file in android

Tags: android, r.java-file

I have this line in R.java file in class string

```
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_BYTECODE=0x7f0a0067;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EMPTY=0x7f0a0066;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_30_DAYS=0x7f0a004a;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_7_DAYS=0x7f0a0049;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_90_DAYS=0x7f0a004b;
    public static final int Î¤Î§Î¤_EVERY_DAY=0x7f0a0048;
```

Gives error duplicate field.

Any idea to solve this issue?

I have clean the project also.

Î¤Î§Î¤ means TXT but i dont know how this shows

Comment: what error you are getting???

Comment: Check your resource file if there is any error.

Comment: Post the logcat error message

Comment: @PiyushGupta there is no error in resource file.

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: I have clean the project and also restart the eclipse but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the encoding of your strings.xml file, ensure it is *UTF-8*.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, check that UTF-8 is set as the encoding the whole project -> Right click on it -> *Properties* -> *Resource* -> under *Text file encoding*.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to open your `R.java`.  The problem is most likely stemming from some resource issue such as a capital letter in a resource name, or an xml issue. Try cleaning the project first. If that doesn't work, you will have to manually check each of your resources (since eclipse doesn't really check that for you).  Of course there have been a few times where eclipse has been the problem for me, so a good restart on eclipse will sometimes work.